# How do I run a code after Woocommerce's billing fields are validated?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce

I want to run some code after Woocommerce's billing fields are validated?

I have tried using the `woocommerce_after_checkout_validation` action but it is not working for some reason.
I placed the function in my theme's functions.php file and I called from form-checkout.php

```
//functions.php
function my_woocommerce_after_checkout_validation( $data, $errors ) {
    var_dump($data);
}
add_action( 'woocommerce_after_checkout_validation', 'my_woocommerce_after_checkout_validation', 10, 2 );

//form-checkout.php
do_action( 'woocommerce_before_checkout_form', $checkout );
```

Why does the above code not work?

Comment: is user already customer?

Comment: @VasimShaikh Yes when I enter email that is already a customer, then I want my function to run at this point.

Comment: you want to check email address on checkout or after checkout?

Comment: @VasimShaikh Basically what I am trying to achieve is, to display login form in a popup modal, if the entered billing email is already existing as a user on the site.

Comment: Popup code will be initiate on client-side there is no need to write code in php for popup.

Comment: The popup is not the concern here, the point is how do I run a code AFTER billing fields are validated.

Comment: instead of this you should check email on email field change or blur event. bind ajax

Comment: No I want to run it after Woocommerce displays the error "Email already exists...".

Answer (score 0):

AJAX request you need to bind if user existing with same email or not
base on this you need open bootstrap mode in response area

```
//Inside function.php or plugin file
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'live_validation' );
add_action('wp_ajax_validate_email', 'validate_email_input');
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_validate_email', 'validate_email_input');

function live_validation() {
    wp_enqueue_script( "validate_email", STRIPE_BASE_URL . 'inc/js/check-email.js', array( 'jquery' ) );
    wp_localize_script( "validate_email", "validateEmail", array( 'ajaxurl' => admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php' ) ) );
}

function validate_email_input() {
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    echo email_exists($email);
    wp_die();
}



// Inside  Script File

jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    jQuery('input[name=email]').keyup(function() { //Email input Name

        var input_value = jQuery(this).val();

        jQuery.post( validateEmail.ajaxurl, { action:'validate_email', email:input_value }, function(data) {
            console.log(data);
        });
    });
});
```